Photosynthesis with reduced sunlight available
I'm trying to figure out certain ways in which plant life could adapt to a fictional world I've created. Since the climate was too cold for life to evolve naturally, there was a terraforming process required to take place beforehand.
The plants in question would be "imported" from a planet that has nearly identical conditions compared to Earth. Beforehand, The Colonizers would perform any measures to help the plants adapt before exposing the specimens to new, different conditions.
The Plant would have to adapt their photosynthesis process to the following new environment:

G-Type Main Sequence Star

Semi Major Axis of the new world: 2.7 AU (Up from Earth which was 1 AU)

Surface Gravity: 0.8g (down from earth which is 1g)

Composition of the Atmosphere
Nitrogen ($N_2$): 68%
Oxygen ($O_2$): 21%
Carbon Dioxide ($CO_2$): 6% (60,000 ppm)
Water Vapor ($H_2O$): 3.5%
Methane ($CH_4$): 1.5%
Noble Gasses such as Argon: 0.5%

Other modifications to the atmosphere may have been made to ensure an average surface temperature identical to Earth, in case the 60000 ppm of $CO_2$ won't do the job.

Day/night cycle: Same as Earth

Amount of natural solar energy reaching this world's surface: 15% (compared to Earth having 100%)

Plant Example Specimen: Spruce Tree (Picea Rubens)

Possible Solution: An increased surface Area is a common adaption in organisms to improve on doing certain tasks: For example the alveoli in the lungs...


Attempting to form a thesis: Since there will be less solar energy compared to Earth, a possible adaption would be to grow over a larger area. To capture a more "earth-like" amount of solar energy for a more earth-like quality and quantity of photosynthesis?
Of course, other adaptions like A smaller amount of reflected Light might also help.

Have you taken a look at already-existing Earth plants? Many survive on a similar amount of light or even less. No fir trees as far as I know.

Yes, i know of plants that prefer places which are less sunlit. Like mosses, fern species and so on, if that is what you mean. But still, i think a plant would have to and would be able to adapt due to this environmental change.

There are plenty of plants that would survive in the low light levels that you suggest. Have a look here: https://smartgardenguide.com/light-requirements-for-indoor-plants/ which environmental change do you think would cause the problems other than light levels?

Due to the fact that I am designing this world to be a moon, tidally locked around a gas giant, there could occur several problems, such as longer day/night cycle and enhanced tidal forces. All not deadly i suppose.
However, they would have to adapt. As the article states: less light = more chloroplasts and darker leaves. I'm sure your average indoor plant growing in a not so well lit room would have an easier time though. As far as i know, these are often tropical species. And tropical climates do in fact exist on my worlds surface.

they could just have a more efficent photo-absorbing molecule. plants have rather inefficent energy absorbtion. other photosythetic organsims have hogher efficency.

you might want to research "lampenflora", the plethora of plants that can grow undergorund, with zero sunlight, on the light from artificial sources alone. if a single low-watt lightbulb in a coal-mine can give enough energy to support several square meters of moss and micro-ferns, then surely they can survive on limited natural sunlight.
